# Pass custom parameters in locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

Actually, I am in a case study and I would like to use Locust for load testing.

As an input, I have a csv file that contains as columns the datetime, number of users and other variable parameters that should be used for each post request as query parameters:

```
datetime,rps,param1,param2
2022-09-18 00:00:00,5,1000,2000
2022-09-18 00:01:00,10,500,1000
```

I have this following class that I  am able to read the CSV file and prepare the stages required for tick function:

```
class StagesShape(LoadTestShape):
```

And in the other hand, I have HttpUser instance that will run the post request:

```
class UserInstance(HttpUser):
```

I would like to know how to pass the param1 and param2 from `StagesShape` class to `UserInstance` class that will be used to be added in the header of the post request.
By the way, the params are not static and they could be different for each stage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [csvreader](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/csvreader.py) from [locust-plugins project](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins)

Something like:

```
from locust_plugins.csvreader import CSVReader
from locust import HttpUser, task

params = CSVReader("test.csv")


class MyUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def index(self):
        param = next(params)
        self.client.get(f"/?first_param={param[0]}&second_param={param[1]}&third_param={param[2]}")

    host = "http://example.com"
```

More information: [How to Run Locust with Different Users](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-multiple-users)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri for your proposition. I agree that we could define our own HttpUser like this using any kind of reading from CSV. But my need is to define specific shape. So, I have to define another class that uses LoadTestShape and the get request will be in the MyUser as you defined. In my case we must send somehow these params from class to another

Answer (score 0):

Data and objects don't have to be stored in the User class and can be referenced from elsewhere. For example, you could have some global variables `param1` and `param2` that contain whatever you need the `MyUser` class to be using for requests and have the `LoadTestShape` class change the value of those variables when appropriate. This would avoid the need for `MyUser` to have to be passed in anything directly.